# Sprites on scrolling tmx map (LibGDX)

Tags: libgdx, sprites, tilemap, scrolling

I have .tmx map loaded, and a camera to see it. The map is bigger than the camera viewport, so I need to move that viewport scrolling the camera.
Now I want to draw a sprite on the map. To do that, at the beginning I used the batch.draw() method, trying to calculate the position relative to the camera, but it didn't worked. After that I found that I could add this line:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

using an Sprite class to draw my object. Howevert, it won't draw on screen; I don't know why. 
Here's my code:

MOVING CAMERA:

```
private void controlCamera()
    {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT) && camera.position.x <= mapPixelWidth + camera.viewportWidth/2)
        {
            camera.position.x += mapSpeed;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) && camera.position.x > camera.viewportWidth/2)
        {
            camera.position.x -= mapSpeed;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) && camera.position.y <= mapPixelHeight + camera.viewportHeight)
        {
            camera.position.y += mapSpeed;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN) && camera.position.y > camera.viewportHeight/2)
        {
            camera.position.y -= mapSpeed;
        }
    }
```

Note that I'm moving the camera between viewport/2 and viewport/2 + map size, since the left down corner is situated at (viewportWidth/2, viewportHeight/2). That's the default position where my .tmx map is drawn.

SPRITE RENDER METHOD:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float stateTime)
    {
        currentFrame = anim.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        sprite.setPosition(getDrawCoords().x, getDrawCoords().y);
        sprite.setSize(currentFrame.getTexture().getWidth()/2, currentFrame.getTexture().getHeight());
        sprite.setRegion(currentFrame);
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
```

GETDRAWCOORDS METHOD:

```
public Vector2 getDrawCoords()
{
    int x =  (int) (map.camera.viewportWidth/2 + map.tilePixelWidth * xMap);
    int y = (int) (map.camera.viewportHeight/2 + map.tilePixelHeight * yMap);
    return new Vector2(x,y);
}
```

I really don't know if I wrote the sprite.setPosition correctly. I tried with lots of things but it never get drawn.

MAIN CLASS RENDER METHOD:

```
public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        map.update(); //Include camera mov
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        map.render(); //draw the map. Include camera.update()
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        units.get(0).render(batch, stateTime); //render my unit
        batch.end();

    }
```

Using a batch.draw() with the texture draw well the sprite in the initial position, but when I try to move the camera it goes crazy. I tried to write the vector position in terms of the other vector, but it doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure of my vector calculus. I'm trying with the sprite and using the projection matrix because I read it give a position relative to camera, but now I can't get my sprite drawn.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!